# add a new element to the sharedPreferences

Tags: android

how to make sure that when I create a new ticket in this case and then I visualize in the second activity and then add a new ticket it goes to me to write with the previously created one, I want every new ticket created not to be overwritten but added

public class Aggiungi extends AppCompatActivity {

```
 public EditText ed_ticket,ed_redattore,ed_targa,ed_dataA,ed_materiale,ed_dataC;
 Button salvataggio;
 public SharedPreferences shared;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_aggiungi);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setTitle("Aggiungi");

    ed_ticket = findViewById(R.id.editex_ticket);
    ed_redattore = findViewById(R.id.editex_redattore);
    ed_targa = findViewById(R.id.editex_targa);
    ed_dataA = findViewById(R.id.editex_dataA);
    ed_materiale = findViewById(R.id.editex_materiale);
    ed_dataC = findViewById(R.id.editex_dataC);

    salvataggio = findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

    salvataggio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            savelista();
        }
    });


}
public void savelista() {

    shared = getSharedPreferences("newListTicket", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();

    editor.putString("ticket",ed_ticket.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.putString("redattore",ed_redattore.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.putString("targa",ed_targa.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.putString("dataA",ed_dataA.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.putString("materiale",ed_materiale.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.putString("dataC",ed_dataC.getText().toString().trim());
    editor.commit();

}
```

}

public class Visualizza extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private MaterialSearchView mMaterialSearch;
private SharedPreferences shared;

private ArrayList<Ticket> mExampleList;

RecyclerView mRecyclearView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

Toolbar mToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview);

    /*//todo modalita FullScreen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/
    mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mMaterialSearch = findViewById(R.id.searchview);

    createExampleList();
    BuildRecyclearView();
    createNewTicket();

}

//TODO nuova scheda Ticket
public void createNewTicket() {

     shared = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        //int ticket = Integer.parseInt(incomingMessages.getString(""));
        String ticket = shared.getString("ticket","");
        String redattore = shared.getString("redattore","");
        String targa = shared.getString("targa","");
        String dataA = shared.getString("dataA","");
        String materiale = shared.getString("materiale","");
        String dataC = shared.getString("dataC","");

        //TODO creazione nuova scheda Ticket
        Ticket Ticket = new Ticket(ticket, redattore, targa, dataA, materiale, dataC);
        mExampleList.add(Ticket);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();



}
//TODO Costruzione della RecyclerView
public void BuildRecyclearView() {
    //todo dichiarazione adapter e chiamiamo il suo costruttore passandogli i parametri necessari
    mRecyclearView = findViewById(R.id.miorecyclerView);
    mRecyclearView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    //todo assegnazione LinearLayoutManager alla RecyclearView
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    //todo set LinearLayoutManager
    mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(mExampleList);
    mRecyclearView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    //TODO COLLEGAMENTO ADAPTER ALLA TABLELYOUT
    mRecyclearView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}
//TODO Esempio di ArrayList
public void createExampleList () {
    mExampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    mExampleList.add(new Ticket("123356", "ALESSANDRO", "EP562WS", "12052018", "Lampeggiante Guasto", "23/10/2018"));
    mExampleList.add(new Ticket("34567", "FRANCESCO", "EP762NS", "19052019", "Motore Guasto", "21/05/2019"));
    mExampleList.add(new Ticket("34353", "ALESSANDRO", "EP760WR", "25052017", "Freni Guasti", "10/12/2018"));
    mExampleList.add(new Ticket("23786","FRANCESCO","EG223KL","27082019","RUOTA SX","28/08/2019"));
}

//TODO Procedura ToolBar Menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    mMaterialSearch.setMenuItem(menuItem);

    // return true;
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

//TODO Procedura di selezione pulsante Menu
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_salva) {

        Toast.makeText(Visualizza.this, "Hai premuto il tasto Salva", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using same `key` for all the items that being added to `SharedPreferences`, then they get overwritten. You can use different keys for each item you are trying to add to `SharedPreferences` so they don't overwrite each other. i.e `ticket_1`, `ticket_2`, etc. But IMHO, Its better to use [SQLite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) for saving these kind of data, Or event better, use [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) library for persisting data.

Answer (score 0):

`SharedPreference` is able to handle `Set`. You need to convert your `ArrayList` into a `Set` while writing, and then convert it back from `Set` into `ArrayList` while reading.

This library [Android SharedPreferences Turbo](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) makes is very easy to put your `ArrayList` into `SharedPreferences`. It internally uses the Sets as said at the start of answer.

Step 1: Create an object of TinyDb

```
TinyDb tinyDb = new TinyDb(context);
```

Step 2: To put the list in SharedPreferences

```
tinyDb.putList("UniqueStringToIdentifyYourList", yourList);
```

Step 3: To retrieve the list

```
tinydb.getList("UniqueStringToIdentifyYourList");
```